# MySQL getting COUNT from multiple columns in the same joined table

Tags: mysql, join, count, sum

I have 2 tables:

- user
- message (which has both *id_user* AND *id_user_from*)

I need a list of basic information about the users, and 3 special columns:

- COUNT of messages received by the user
- COUNT of messages sent by the user
- SUM of all the views (both sent and received) of the user's messages

This is my current query:

```
SELECT
SUM(case when message.id_user = user.id_user THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS q_received,
SUM(case when message.id_user_from = user.id_user THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS q_sent,
SUM(message.views) AS views,
user.id_user AS id_user, user.name AS name, user.lastname AS lastname, user.date_login AS date_login
FROM user
    LEFT JOIN message ON message.id_user = user.id_user
ORDER BY user.date_login DESC
```

The sums are all wrong. Here's the sqlfiddle with all the necessary tables and some records as example:
http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/4fd838/2

Thanks!

Comment: Of course it's wrong.  You are summing and counting for all users.  You need to aggregate the sum and the count for each user.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would do this like below:

```
select 
coalesce(SUM(recv),0) AS q_received,
coalesce(SUM(sent),0) AS q_sent,
coalesce(SUM(views),0) as views,
user.id_user AS id_user, user.name AS name, user.lastname AS lastname, user.date_login AS date_login
FROM user
left join
 (  
 select id_user, count(*) as recv, 0  as sent,sum(views) as views from message group by id_user
 union all
 select id_user_from, 0, count(*) as sent,sum(views) as views from message group by id_user_from
 ) t
on user.id_user=t.id_user
group by user.id_user
order by user.id_user;

Result:
q_received  q_sent  views   id_user name    lastname            date_login
4           2       32      1               Rigoberto   Santos  2018-03-21T17:37:28Z
0           2        6      2               Coquita Perlini     2018-03-21T17:34:59Z
1           1        2      3               Miguel  Bianchi     2018-03-21T14:26:11Z
0           0        0      4               Ramiro  Alvarado    2018-03-21T14:26:06Z
1           1       24      5               Andrea  Lucas       2018-03-21T17:35:04Z
```

Comment: Sent and Received sums are working fine, the views column is a little more complicated though, it should not be the sum of recv and sent, it should be the sum of the "views" field for all messages that the user has sent or received.

Comment: Pls give me the expected value of views for all user_id. Thanks.

Comment: I edited my answer, pls let me know if views is correct or not. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

You may try this:

```
select t1.num as q_received, t2.num as q_sent, u.id_user from user u
left join (
 select count(*) as num, id_user from message group by id_user
) t1 on t1.id_user = u.id_user
left join (
 select count(*) as num, id_user_from from message group by id_user_from
) t2 on t2.id_user_from = u.id_user
```